# Acquiring node in nodejs + xpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, xpath

I have an element on a webpage which gives the following XPath source via Chrome Inspector
`//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a`

I want to get this node programatically in Node.js.

```
var parser = new parse5.Parser();
var document = parser.parse(data);
var xhtmldoc = xmlserializer.serializeToString(document);
var xdom = new xmldomparser().parseFromString(xhtmldoc);
var selector = xpath.useNamespaces({"doc": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"});
var node = selector('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a', xdom);
console.log(node);
```

But it consistently returns an empty object with any variation of xpath. Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to that you are declaring the correct namespace and a prefix:

```
 var selector = xpath.useNamespaces({"doc": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"});
```

but then you do not use it in the path expression. Prefix elements with `doc:` in your path expression:

```
var node = selector('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/doc:div/doc:table/doc:tbody/doc:tr/doc:td/doc:table/doc:tbody/doc:tr/doc:td[2]/doc:table/doc:tbody/doc:tr[3]/doc:td/doc:table[2]/doc:tbody/doc:tr[2]/doc:td[2]/doc:a', xdom);
```

That said, the XPath expression you got back from Chrome Inspector is not really handy, and only relies on positions of nodes. If you explain what you are trying to find in that document (and show the document, of course), people could suggest an alternative expression.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but is it possible to just prefix doc once rather than attaching it to the whole path?

Comment: @GauravJoseph I'm not sure that's possible with node.js - if you'd like to research yourself: look for "Xpath default namespace". But in my opinion, it's not a good idea anyway, because it obfuscates the code unnecessarily.

Comment: @GauravJoseph Since I was looking into it anyway, according to [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath) I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I did check the page actually before asking here, but the examples were not clear enough. I was originally trying to use a default namespace type syntax, I was unaware that all the nodes had to be prefixed with the namespace.